# How to check if ios safari/chrome is in lockdown mode for a ReactJS Webapp

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

As per the title, how would I check the safari/chrome browser used by an iphone/ios user is in lock down mode?

I've got a web app which works fine, but recently when testing on ios 17.2 indexedDB doesn't work, I cannot add files, it just crashes with no error message. so I assume its in lockdown mode. I did do a test on browserstack with the same ios version in safari and it worked without issue, any help would be appericated.

Resources I've looked at:

- https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710176
- Swift code `let isLockdownModeEnabled = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "LDMGlobalEnabled") as? Bool) ?? false` however I cant access UserDefaults via javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after quite some time I did find a solution, it was due to safari/ios/macos's IndexedDB not supporting storing data in a specific format.